# how to select image from JSON parsed in Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4.2

I am using JSON parsing, I put data in array named **JSON Array**. In console it looks like

```
JSON Array=(
 {
    "created_by" = 42;
    "created_on" = "2012-02-29 11:23:37";
    "file_description" = "";
    "file_is_downloadable" = 0;
    "file_is_forSale" = 0;
    "file_is_product_image" = 1;
    "file_meta" = "";
    "file_mimetype" = "image/jpeg";
    "file_params" = "";
    "file_title" = "hand shovel";
    "file_type" = product;
    "file_url" = "images/stories/virtuemart/product/cca3cd5db813ee6badf6a3598832f2fc.jpg";
    "file_url_thumb" = "images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/cca3cd5db813ee6badf6a3598832f2fc_90x90.jpg";
    "locked_by" = 0;
    "locked_on" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    "modified_by" = 42;
    "modified_on" = "2012-02-29 11:23:37";
    ordering = 0;
    "product_name" = "Hand Shovel";
    published = 0;
    shared = 0;
    "virtuemart_category_id" = 1;
    "virtuemart_media_id" = 13;
    "virtuemart_product_id" = 1;
    "virtuemart_vendor_id" = 1;
},

    {
    "created_by" = 42;
    "created_on" = "2012-02-29 11:35:09";
    "file_description" = "";
    "file_is_downloadable" = 0;
    "file_is_forSale" = 0;
    "file_is_product_image" = 1;
    "file_meta" = "";
    "file_mimetype" = "image/jpeg";
    "file_params" = "";
    "file_title" = "our ladder";
    "file_type" = product;
    "file_url" = "images/stories/virtuemart/product/8cb8d644ef299639b7eab25829d13dbc.jpg";
    "file_url_thumb" = "images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/8cb8d644ef299639b7eab25829d13dbc_90x90.jpg";
    "locked_by" = 0;
    "locked_on" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    "modified_by" = 42;
    "modified_on" = "2012-02-29 11:35:09";
    ordering = 0;
    "product_name" = Ladder;
    published = 0;
    shared = 0;
    "virtuemart_category_id" = 3;
    "virtuemart_media_id" = 8;
    "virtuemart_product_id" = 2;
    "virtuemart_vendor_id" = 1;
},
```

Now  from this i need to select "**file_url_thumb**" which is actually image in seperate array.
please let me know how can i do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Show the code that you have for parsing your JSON and extracting the data and explain what you have tried and in what way it isn't working. We aren't here to write your code for you.

Comment: [json objectForKey:@"file_url_thumb"];

Comment: Also we can see their are two groups in which separate "virtuemart_category_id" is there depending on that id how can i put that complete group content in some other array

Comment: @NickBull actually first i need to separate these two group in two array depending on "virtuemart_category_id" for this i am using text field. i.e. if enter 3 in text field , group content "virtuemart_category_id"=3 must get seperated in some other array. and then out of that i need to search  "file_url_thumb" which is actually image, to show in image view

Comment: i tried this for (int i=0; i<[jsonArray count]; i++)
    {
        if ([[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"virtuemart_category_id"]isEqual:compare]) 
        {
            [ tempArray addObject:[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Selected Array=%@",containsAnother);

Comment: where compare is NSString *compare;
    compare=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"file_url_thumb"]

Comment: @NickBull can you please suggest something

Comment: What are you using for your JSON parsing library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Your array has two dictionary ..


for(NSMutableDictionary *dict in JSON_Array){
       NSString *urlString =  [dict objectForKey:@"file_url_thumb"];
       if(urlString){
       NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:urlString];
       NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url]];
       UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
       //show your image on imageview
      }
}
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str_URL =[ [json objectAtIndex:anIndex] valueForKey:@"file_url_thumb"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *urlString = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"file_url_thumb"];
```

This will give you value for "file_url_thumb" as a string.